# How best to Germinate Sweetcorn

Tags: germination, sweetcorn

I'm wanting to grow some sweetcorn (Its mid spring here, so I believe I should have enough time).    My concern is that the sweetcorn is going to be grown very close to the home of my wifes free-range chickens - so I have a couple of questions -

1. If i plant the sweetcorn 3 cm below the soil, are the chickens likely to 
   find and consume it ?
2. Is there a simple way to germinate sweetcorn in a controlled environment
   such that I can get it to a size where I can plant it without having it
   be of interest to the chickens ?   (inside or outside, maybe in a 
   plastic container ? )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is kinda sweet...yes, Davidgo, you can germinate your corn (please make sure the package is labeled NON-GMO) by soaking the kernels in water the night before you plant.  Chickens are worth the effort to protect your garden.  I would get a rabbit/chicken fence put up (easy) that is 1 and 1/2 feet above surface and 6" below surface.  Doesn't have to be pretty and can always be improved.  Those chickens are worth every egg, every insect they gobble and every poop of fertilizer.  Grins.  I have 25 bunnies and this simple fencing keeps them out of our garden.  They are running around pooping great fertilizer pellets...I just love 'em.

Another inexpensive thing you could do.   Go get 'row cloth' and lay that stuff over your newly planted corn until you are able to get that little fence installed.

And yes, those chickens will find your germinating seeds, dig them up and eat 'em.  If you cover your seeded area with row cloth, securing the edges with soil, the row cloth allows water and sun in, holds onto the heat a bit more for the spring transition and will give you about a month before you have to give in and put up a simple 18" high or better, field wire fence buried 4-6" below the surface.  Very inexpensive and this is the best way to make everyone happy!

Corn does not transplant well, so starts are very iffy.  Harmony with animals, neighbors and wives is completely within our power.  Very worth the effort...